# Use emacsclient -t when committing in Git

Tags: git, bash, shell, emacs

In my `.bash_profile`, I use this:

```
export EDITOR=emacsclient
alias e='emacsclient -t'
```

When I commit changes with Git, it will open a new  emacs window, but with `emacs --daemon`.
How can I set my default Git editor to be emacs with the t flag enabled?

Comment: I'm sure Moritz Bunkus has the answer, but I'm somewhat confused by your wording. Are you saying you want your standard editor to be `emacsclient -t` (in which case you could simply specify that for the value of `EDITOR`), or that you want the git editor to be different to your standard editor. And if you are running `emacs --daemon`, then emacsclient will be connecting to that `-t` flag or otherwise, so I'm not sure what your comment about that meant.

Comment: Actually,the requirement comes from this:when emacs starts up,it took some time,that`s why I use emacs --daemon.when I use git commit,it will open a new emacs,thus I have to wait .so I want to open a emacs window use emacsclient -t. Am I clear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the true reason for this is the version of emacs.there is a default emacs on mac, which version doesnot have the option "-t".Also ,it seems that git doesnot read the setting in .bash_profile

Answer (score 20):

```
git config --global core.editor 'emacsclient -t -a=\"\"'
```

This will start a daemon if there is not already one running.

You may be having issues with quotation marks, as it shows up in my .gitconfig as

```
[core]
    editor = emacsclient -t -a=\\\"\\\"
```

Comment: emacsclient: invalid option -- t
Try `emacsclient --help' for more information
error: There was a problem with the editor 'emacsclient -t -a=\"\"'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option. This is the output when I use you settings,Where can I get these specification about "quotation marks"??

Comment: Surely there's no need to escape the double-quotes within a single-quoted string?

Comment: @newlife What os are you using and what version of emacs?  http://linux.die.net/man/1/emacsclient

Comment: @tcaswell ,I am using mac osx 10.7,,,

Comment: @newlife This may be a limitation of emacs on mac.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/emacsclient.1.html does not list -t as a valid option.  Does `emacsclient -t` work from the command line?  I do not have a mac to test this on (only linux).  Reading your other comments again, if you always have a daemon running, you can drop the -a="" part.

Comment: just use `emacsclient -t -a=`. you don't need the quotes

Answer (score 5):

```
export GIT_EDITOR="`which emacsclient` -t -s $EMACS_SERVER_FILE"
```

git seems to muck with the PATH variable before calling your EDITOR or GIT_EDITOR so the built in emacsclient from /usr/bin gets called even if normally the emacsclient from your more up to date Emacs would be called. I solved this by getting the path to the executable from a subprocess which has its own environment I believe (either way it works...).

Tested on OS X 10.8.2 with Emacs 24.1 built locally, server running and clients connecting via socket.

I have not tested tcp clients.

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't say "Read That Fine Manual", but in this case it simply applies. `git commit --help` has this to say about the topic:

```
ENVIRONMENT AND CONFIGURATION VARIABLES
   The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen
   from the GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration
   variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment
   variable (in that order). See git-var(1) for details.
```

Comment: [core]
        editor = "emacsclient -t"  I use this in .gitconfig.However,it doesnot work,any suggestion??

Comment: If you define `GIT_EDITOR=emacsclient`, a new Emacs instance is always launched even if your daemon is running. However if you define it at your `~/.gitconfig` file through `core.editor`, it correctly connects to your running instance.